# Make AngularJS produce an error for bad interpolation

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I reference a variable in the $scope with the {{variable_name}} format in the html, angular will substitute this with the referenced variable. However, if I type a bunch of gibberish as the variable_name instead of something that I have set, angular will just completely ignore it.

This is a very nice feature to have in production - but during development I would rather it produce an error in the browser console or something like that so I know that I have made a typo or some other mistake.

Is there any way to make angular produce an error upon bad interpolation? If my question is not clear enough please tell me and I will try to improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some trick like this:

```
{{data || "no such data"}}
```

If you don't have such a scope variable `data`, then it will show the alternative data(no such data).

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed

Comment: Glad helped you. All the best.